# Problem with python's sort() when sorting files

Tags: python, sorting

I am trying to make a python script to rename files in a folder in a sequence.

I looped through the files and placed them in a list which I then, sorted with with sort()

But unfortunately It doesn't seem to work as the file name are string

My code:

```py
files_list = []
files = os.listdir(dir_path) 
for index, file in enumerate(files):
    filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(file)
    files_list.append(filename + file_extension)

print(files)
files.sort()
print(files)
```

Raw data:
`['1.png', '3.jpg' '2.gif' 'myfile_1.png', 'eclipsu.jpg', 'apple.gif']`

What I want:
`['1.png', '2.gif' '3.jph' 'apple.gif', 'eclipsu.jpg', 'myfiles_1.png']`

Comment: what do you mean "doesn't seem to work"?  what are you expecting this code to do?  why are you putting things into `files_list` but sorting `files`?  also splitting paths and then joining them again serves no useful purpose

Comment: Forgive me for that.

Comment: it's not about forgiving you, it's that you've not explained your problem in a way that can be usefully answered.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask has some pointers

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the key args in sort()

```
a = ['1.png', '3.jpg' '2.gif' 'myfile_1.png', 'eclipsu.jpg', 'apple.gif']
a.sort(key= lambda x: x.split('.'))
```

output

```
['1.png', '2.gif', '3.jpg', 'apple.gif', 'eclipsu.jpg', 'myfile_1.png']
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for helping me out but it doesn't work :(

[Out put](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/725230136877907998/847145813372960800/unknown.png)

:(

Comment: @TheRealRJ what exactly do you want to do, your question was sorting the list.??

Comment: Yes! I want to sort the list, the list contains file name. I want to sort the file names! The sort() only seem to work with ints, But my list contains file names! i can not do turn it into int with int().

Comment: the solution i gave, delivered the output that you requested